# AMPL Group Assignment programming

Tags: ampl

I'm trying to do an exercise for a project in AMPL and am getting stuck. I think I'm on the right path but I'm not too sure. This is the question:

> "The professor in charge of an industrial engineering design course is
>   faced with the problem of assigning 28 students to eight projects.
>   Each student must be assigned to one project, and each project group
>   must have 3 or 4 students. The students have been asked to rank the
>   projects, with 1 being the best ranking and higher numbers
>   representing lower rankings. The professor’s goal is to assign
>   projects to every student while minimizing the sum of rankings"

I need to formulate this model in AMPL and use this data to assign the groups:
[Ranking Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HclyF.png)

This is my MOD File So far, I think I need to use the VAR function but don't really know how to make it fit

```
set Student;
set Group;
param rank {Student,Group} >=0;
var list{student} binary >=0;
minimize rank:
sum{i in student} list[i]*rank[i];
subject to target {j in group}:
sum {i in student} list[i]*grouping[i,j] >=1;
```

Data File:

```
data;
set Group:= A ED EZ G H1 H2 RB SC;
set Student:= Allen Black Chung Clark Conners Cumming Demming Eng Farmer Forest Goodman Harris Holmes Johnson Knorr Manheim Morris Nathan Neuman Patrick Rolins Schuman Silver Stein Stock Truman Wolman Young;
param grouping :
A ED EZ G H1 H2 RB SC:=
Allen 1 3 4 7 7 5 2 6
Black 6 4 3 5 5 7 1 3
Chung 6 2 3 1 1 7 5 4
Clark 7 6 1 2 2 3 5 4
Conners 7 6 1 3 3 4 5 2
Cumming 6 7 4 2 2 3 5 1
Demming 2 5 4 6 6 1 3 7
Eng 4 7 2 1 1 6 3 5
Farmer 7 6 5 2 2 1 3 4
Forest 6 7 2 5 5 1 3 4
Goodman 7 6 2 4 4 5 1 3
Harris 4 7 5 3 3 1 2 6
Holmes 6 7 4 2 2 3 5 1
Johnson 7 2 4 6 6 5 3 1
Knorr  7 4 1 2 2 5 6 3
Manheim 4 7 2 1 1 3 6 5
Morris 7 5 4 6 6 3 1 2
Nathan 4 7 5 6 6 3 1 2
Neuman 7 5 4 6 6 3 1 2
Patrick 1 7 5 4 4 2 3 6
Rollins 6 2 3 1 1 7 5 4
Schuman 4 7 3 5 5 1 2 6
Silver 4 7 3 1 1 2 5 6
Stein 6 4 2 5 5 7 1 3
Stock 5 2 1 6 6 7 4 3
Truman 6 3 2 7 7 5 1 4
Wolman 6 7 4 2 2 3 5 1
Young 1 3 4 7 7 6 2 5
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, but you need to think more of how to represent the assignments. In particular, what does variable `list` represent in your model:

```
var list{student} binary >=0;
```

Perhaps, try to formulate it in a textual form as if you are writing a comment. For example:

```
# Ranking of project g by student s.
param rank {s in Student, g in Group} >=0;
```

Since this is an exercise you are supposed to do yourself, I won't give away the solution.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I tried that and it still was saying it couldn't define things. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @user3545910 What do you mean by "couldn't define things". Do you get an error?

Comment: I got "Student is not defined" but I define it in the DAT file so I'm not sure why it's saying that. Maybe I should remove student from the mod?

Comment: AMPL is case-sensitive while you define the set as "Student" but refer to "student".

Comment: ampl: model Problem1.mod;

Problem1.mod, line 1 (offset 4):
 Student is already defined

Problem1.mod, line 4 (offset 60):
 student is not defined
ampl:

Comment: It keeps saying something is "already defined" but if I take it away then it says it's "not defined". I fixed the capitalization errors, thanks

Comment: You can use reset to clear the declarations before including the model file again.

Comment: I did, I've reset it everytime

Comment: Now I got a syntax error for this line
sum{i in student} list[i]*rank[i];

Comment: You use the same name "rank" for objective and parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is just rewriting the parameter as a variable. I would use

```
set student;
set group;

var assign{i in student, j in group} binary;
param pref{i in student, j in group};

maximize totalPref:
     sum{i in student, j in group} pref[i,j]*assign[i,j];

subject to exactly_one_group {i in student}:
      sum {j in group} assign[i,j] =1;

subject to min3{j in group}:
     sum{i in student} assign[i,j]>=3;

subject to max4{j in group}:
     sum{i in student} assign[i,j]<=4;

##########
data;
set group:= A ED EZ G H1 H2 RB SC;
set student:= Allen Black Chung Clark Conners Cumming Demming Eng Farmer Forest Goodman Harris Holmes Johnson Knorr Manheim Morris Nathan Neuman Patrick Rollins Schuman Silver Stein Stock Truman Wolman Young;

param pref:
          A ED EZ G H1 H2 RB SC:=
Allen         1 3 4 7 7 5 2 6
Black        6 4 3 5 5 7 1 3
Chung      6 2 3 1 1 7 5 4
Clark         7 6 1 2 2 3 5 4
Conners    7 6 1 3 3 4 5 2
Cumming  6 7 4 2 2 3 5 1
Demming  2 5 4 6 6 1 3 7
Eng           4 7 2 1 1 6 3 5
Farmer      7 6 5 2 2 1 3 4
Forest        6 7 2 5 5 1 3 4
Goodman  7 6 2 4 4 5 1 3
Harris        4 7 5 3 3 1 2 6
Holmes     6 7 4 2 2 3 5 1
Johnson    7 2 4 6 6 5 3 1
Knorr         7 4 1 2 2 5 6 3
Manheim   4 7 2 1 1 3 6 5
Morris        7 5 4 6 6 3 1 2
Nathan      4 7 5 6 6 3 1 2
Neuman    7 5 4 6 6 3 1 2
Patrick      1 7 5 4 4 2 3 6
Rollins      6 2 3 1 1 7 5 4
Schuman 4 7 3 5 5 1 2 6
Silver       4 7 3 1 1 2 5 6
Stein        6 4 2 5 5 7 1 3
Stock       5 2 1 6 6 7 4 3
Truman    6 3 2 7 7 5 1 4
Wolman    6 7 4 2 2 3 5 1
Young        1 3 4 7 7 6 2 5;
```

Think of transport optimization by ussign a variable with two indicies.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are allowed to assign up to two groups to un-qualified students. How would you reformulate the problem and find the new solution, with preference still applying? * means un-qualified

```
param pref:
          A ED EZ  G H1 H2 RB SC:=
Allen     1  3  *  7  7  5  *  6
Black     6  *  3  5  5  *  1  3
Chung     6  2  3  1  *  7  5  *
Clark     *  6  1  *  2  3  5  4
Conners   7  6  1  3  3  *  *  2
```